# Are these two DFAs equivalent?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, restricted-time

Two Deterministic Finite Automata or [DFAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) can be checked to see if they accept same set of strings in polynomial time.  See [section 3.3 of this](https://scholarworks.rit.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=7944&context=theses) for a long list of methods and this [SO](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/81813/is-the-equality-of-two-dfas-a-decidable-problem) question/answer for a much shorter list.

**Input**

Your input will be two [DFAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton). In order to be able to test your code, I have provided DFAs in the following format. This is taken  directly from [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/automata-1.14/doc/chap2.html#X811E5FC2849C5644) (and slightly simplified).

```
Automaton( Type, Size, Alphabet, TransitionTable, Initial, Accepting )
```

For the input, Type will always be "det".  Size is a positive integer representing the number of states of the automaton. Alphabet is the number of letters of the alphabet. TransitionTable is the transition matrix. The entries are non-negative integers not greater than the size of the automaton. We may write a 0 to mean that no transition is present.  Initial and Accepting are, respectively, the lists of initial and accepting states.  You can assume there will be exactly one initial state.

For example:

```
Automaton("det",4,2,[ [ 1, 3, 4, 0 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ],[ 3 ],[ 2, 3, 4 ])
```

This has transition table:

```
   |  1  2  3  4  
-----------------
 a |  1  3  4     
 b |  1  2  3  4  
Initial state:    [ 3 ]
Accepting states: [ 2, 3, 4 ]
```

And diagram:

[image]

It is equivalent to:

```
Automaton("det",3,2,[ [ 1, 3, 1 ], [ 1, 2, 3 ] ],[ 2 ],[ 2, 3 ])
```

which has diagram:

[image]

In order to remove parsing as a significant part of this challenge, you are free to perform trivial parsing of the input format before giving it to your code. This means you can delete any part or parts, reorder and change one type of bracket to another before passing the input to your code. For example, the previous example can be given as

```
3,2,[ [ 1, 3, 1 ], [ 1, 2, 3 ] ],[ 2 ],[ 2, 3 ]
```

if that helps.

Here is a more complicated example,

```
Automaton("det",6,4,[ [ 0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 1, 3, 5, 6, 0, 0 ], [ 2, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0 ] ],[ 1 ],[ 1, 4, 5, 6 ])
```

has diagram:

[image]

It is equivalent to:

```
Automaton("det",5,4,[ [ 2, 2, 2, 4, 5 ], [ 2, 2, 3, 1, 4 ], [ 2, 2, 3, 1, 4 ], [ 2, 2, 5, 1, 4 ] ],[ 3 ],[ 1, 3 ])
```

with diagram:

[image]

## More examples of equivalent DFAs

1.

```
Automaton("det",18,4,[ [ 2, 2, 6, 10, 2, 6, 7, 16, 14, 10, 18, 14, 7, 14, 15, 16, 7, 18 ], [ 3, 3, 7, 11, 3, 7, 15, 11, 7, 17, 15, 18\
, 18, 7, 15, 17, 15, 15 ], [ 4, 4, 8, 7, 4, 13, 15, 15, 16, 7, 8, 7, 15, 7, 15, 15, 16, 13 ], [ 5, 5, 9, 12, 5, 14, 7, 13, 9, 14, 17, 12, \
13, 14, 15, 7, 17, 7 ] ],[ 1 ],[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18 ])
```

```
Automaton("det",16,4,[ [ 1, 2, 15, 15, 5, 6, 7, 7, 6, 2, 16, 12, 12, 16, 15, 16 ], [ 1, 3, 1, 7, 9, 15, 1, 1, 15, 8, 7, 3, 8, 15, 1, \
15 ], [ 1, 1, 2, 1, 13, 4, 4, 10, 10, 1, 15, 15, 15, 2, 1, 15 ], [ 1, 15, 3, 4, 5, 16, 15, 3, 14, 4, 11, 16, 11, 14, 15, 16 ] ],[ 5 ],[ 2,\
 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 ])
```

  2.

```
Automaton("det",50,4,[ [ 2, 2, 9, 13, 17, 9, 13, 17, 9, 24, 28, 30, 13, 33, 36, 30, 17, 9, 13, 9, 13, 39, 30, 24, 25, 44, 42, 28, 24, 30, 47, 39, 33, 50, 36, 36, 42, 46, 39, 25, 24, 42, 43, 44, 36, 46, 47, 42, 25, 50 ], [ 3, 6, 10, 14, 18, 10, 14, 20, 10, 25, 14, 10, 32, 34, 34, 38, 20, 10, 14, 10, 14, 38, 10, 25, 43, 34, 25, 45, 46, 10, 32, 49, 34, 43, 34, 49, 50, 50, 49, 50, 46, 25, 43, 49, 49, 50, 45, 50, 43, 43 ], [ 4, 7, 11, 15, 19, 11, 15, 21, 22, 26, 26, 31, 15, 11, 25, 15, 21, 11, 15, 11, 15, 40, 15, 40, 43, 43, 44, 26, 26, 15, 44, 31, 41, 26, 47, 25, 25, 22, 40, 43, 40, 25, 43, 43, 47, 41, 44, 44, 44, 40 ], [ 5, 8, 12, 16, 5, 12, 16, 8, 23, 27, 29, 12, 23, 35, 37, 16, 8, 12, 16, 12, 16, 41, 23, 42, 25, 40, 27, 27, 29, 23, 48, 45, 37, 49, 35, 42, 37, 48, 42, 40, 41, 42, 43, 25, 45, 37, 27, 48, 49, 25 ] ],[ 1 ],[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50 ])
```

```
Automaton("det",39,4,[ [ 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 24, 7, 8, 22, 20, 8, 32, 18, 18, 3, 19, 25, 18, 19, 20, 25, 22, 23, 24, 25, 25, 24, 23, 5, 2, 35, 32, 19, 19, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36 ], [ 1, 38, 1, 23, 15, 9, 11, 26, 23, 28, 26, 10, 9, 26, 1, 3, 22, 26, 3, 28, 22, 23, 1, 15, 3, 3, 15, 1, 28, 27, 10, 27, 23, 23, 38, 15, 28, 15, 28 ], [ 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4, 12, 6, 6, 31, 31, 37, 37, 30, 5, 5, 29, 37, 3, 21, 4, 21, 4, 4, 4, 29, 30, 29, 1, 5, 29, 37, 5, 3, 29, 3, 3, 2, 2 ], [ 1, 16, 3, 4, 3, 21, 7, 18, 33, 39, 14, 13, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 34, 21, 34, 3, 19, 19, 16, 38, 15, 4, 33, 17, 18, 33, 34, 16, 19, 34, 38, 39 ] ],[ 7 ],[ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39 ])
```

3.

```
Automaton("det",288,4,[[2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 6, 10, 14, 18, 25, 29, 33, 36, 40, 43, 46, 36, 53, 10, 14, 18, 10, 14, 18, 25, 29, 60, 36, 29, 67, 71, 75, 77, 81, 83, 87, 88, 90, 94, 40, 98, 46, 104, 108, 111, 46, 116, 120, 75, 123, 127, 129, 53, 10, 14, 131, 129, 71, 75, 136, 140, 143, 146, 87, 149, 75, 67, 68, 155, 153, 156, 159, 161, 163, 75, 165, 77, 170, 81, 172, 81, 67, 88, 123, 156, 146, 87, 88, 156, 90, 183, 186, 188, 87, 90, 183, 94, 192, 143, 197, 199, 116, 75, 104, 108, 204, 172, 108, 208, 120, 127, 159, 90, 199, 163, 159, 215, 156, 149, 120, 153, 217, 123, 218, 131, 221, 127, 159, 87, 123, 225, 88, 155, 67, 165, 136, 227, 143, 221, 123, 218, 221, 143, 68, 67, 88, 123, 127, 143, 217, 68, 67, 153, 154, 155, 156, 234, 235, 159, 120, 161, 237, 143, 217, 165, 143, 241, 199, 188, 242, 197, 75, 67, 165, 241, 217, 248, 250, 172, 146, 221, 161, 225, 234, 111, 186, 153, 75, 217, 75, 188, 192, 257, 188, 68, 120, 90, 186, 127, 90, 208, 146, 221, 259, 140, 120, 235, 208, 165, 262, 199, 188, 68, 120, 215, 267, 217, 218, 250, 83, 75, 165, 75, 215, 225, 208, 234, 71, 149, 153, 75, 235, 208, 234, 67, 265, 272, 233, 241, 143, 120, 242, 257, 155, 153, 143, 153, 248, 267, 250, 116, 120, 75, 237, 71, 235, 250, 163, 259, 227, 153, 262, 67, 75, 155, 233, 272, 265, 116, 241, 281, 272, 68, 149, 120, 155, 283, 163, 67, 208, 285, 265, 287, 233, 285, 68, 287, 68], [3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 7, 11, 15, 22, 26, 30, 15, 37, 41, 44, 47, 50, 54, 11, 15, 19, 11, 15, 22, 26, 30, 61, 37, 30, 68, 72, 30, 78, 47, 84, 26, 30, 91, 37, 96, 99, 102, 105, 109, 112, 115, 117, 109, 122, 124, 128, 130, 54, 11, 15, 130, 132, 72, 30, 137, 141, 122, 147, 132, 150, 30, 68, 154, 109, 68, 157, 109, 162, 164, 30, 166, 168, 99, 102, 173, 175, 176, 177, 124, 128, 147, 132, 30, 72, 168, 184, 115, 189, 132, 96, 99, 37, 166, 195, 96, 99, 201, 150, 105, 109, 205, 164, 109, 154, 109, 157, 109, 211, 112, 213, 109, 154, 72, 109, 195, 208, 215, 124, 208, 130, 150, 166, 224, 26, 124, 157, 30, 226, 217, 166, 115, 213, 150, 30, 124, 208, 150, 195, 208, 176, 177, 124, 72, 224, 208, 233, 217, 68, 154, 195, 214, 195, 208, 109, 109, 236, 117, 195, 208, 214, 195, 201, 99, 173, 166, 168, 177, 68, 246, 213, 215, 68, 251, 173, 147, 150, 254, 166, 195, 99, 175, 208, 30, 215, 122, 164, 166, 251, 173, 154, 195, 78, 258, 166, 168, 154, 147, 150, 260, 141, 226, 217, 154, 214, 254, 184, 263, 154, 195, 154, 109, 208, 208, 269, 84, 177, 246, 150, 154, 166, 215, 195, 166, 150, 208, 150, 208, 215, 195, 215, 213, 195, 208, 213, 150, 195, 166, 254, 109, 68, 224, 233, 68, 109, 236, 201, 226, 150, 213, 166, 208, 277, 117, 278, 213, 233, 236, 215, 279, 195, 208, 224, 201, 117, 280, 254, 195, 208, 109, 109, 226, 213, 213, 215, 215, 277, 280, 195, 208, 236, 233, 195, 208], [4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 8, 12, 16, 23, 27, 31, 34, 38, 42, 12, 48, 51, 55, 12, 16, 20, 12, 16, 23, 56, 58, 62, 51, 65, 69, 73, 76, 79, 69, 85, 42, 89, 92, 95, 42, 100, 48, 106, 31, 113, 48, 118, 68, 48, 125, 48, 51, 55, 12, 16, 62, 51, 133, 135, 138, 56, 144, 62, 148, 151, 48, 144, 154, 154, 155, 69, 118, 154, 69, 48, 161, 79, 171, 69, 174, 69, 69, 178, 180, 69, 85, 148, 138, 182, 92, 95, 155, 135, 42, 92, 95, 148, 193, 76, 198, 200, 118, 48, 202, 58, 62, 206, 207, 69, 209, 210, 89, 92, 200, 135, 178, 216, 69, 174, 68, 68, 138, 202, 65, 219, 222, 48, 118, 148, 56, 138, 118, 154, 69, 155, 138, 228, 144, 206, 106, 229, 174, 144, 154, 144, 138, 202, 48, 144, 138, 154, 144, 68, 154, 154, 69, 228, 133, 152, 165, 154, 69, 182, 240, 155, 135, 155, 200, 135, 243, 198, 210, 244, 155, 165, 152, 249, 144, 206, 219, 252, 154, 178, 255, 113, 155, 155, 210, 240, 135, 135, 65, 151, 48, 155, 209, 92, 155, 210, 92, 244, 62, 206, 138, 202, 68, 151, 144, 161, 68, 200, 135, 265, 165, 266, 73, 152, 207, 144, 62, 48, 161, 76, 249, 138, 69, 271, 133, 73, 265, 135, 151, 144, 266, 144, 155, 182, 133, 155, 182, 161, 274, 151, 161, 265, 135, 155, 266, 151, 144, 138, 161, 275, 69, 73, 276, 144, 135, 138, 249, 68, 68, 244, 135, 161, 151, 144, 155, 138, 155, 151, 144, 155, 151, 161, 161, 249, 69, 69, 244, 144, 155, 271, 276, 144, 155, 266, 265], [5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 9, 13, 17, 24, 28, 32, 35, 39, 28, 45, 49, 52, 9, 13, 17, 21, 13, 17, 24, 57, 59, 63, 64, 66, 70, 74, 32, 80, 82, 86, 28, 32, 93, 39, 97, 101, 103, 107, 110, 114, 66, 119, 121, 49, 126, 49, 52, 9, 13, 17, 63, 64, 134, 59, 139, 142, 145, 63, 64, 152, 66, 153, 68, 144, 70, 158, 160, 151, 134, 66, 167, 169, 101, 134, 59, 70, 82, 179, 181, 82, 86, 64, 66, 74, 169, 185, 187, 190, 97, 191, 101, 64, 194, 196, 191, 101, 160, 103, 203, 160, 63, 103, 121, 195, 110, 179, 110, 212, 114, 214, 167, 213, 134, 160, 153, 121, 158, 203, 187, 220, 223, 66, 119, 57, 142, 139, 59, 151, 134, 187, 66, 214, 152, 66, 107, 230, 231, 153, 144, 145, 139, 203, 103, 232, 187, 151, 152, 153, 154, 68, 70, 214, 187, 121, 160, 68, 238, 239, 230, 70, 214, 187, 101, 59, 194, 169, 179, 245, 247, 214, 232, 70, 152, 66, 220, 253, 144, 194, 196, 101, 70, 187, 194, 256, 190, 231, 66, 152, 66, 195, 196, 80, 247, 194, 169, 213, 63, 103, 139, 203, 261, 152, 68, 239, 121, 185, 264, 213, 214, 68, 268, 121, 121, 145, 63, 139, 270, 223, 195, 66, 238, 239, 187, 74, 230, 231, 121, 266, 153, 232, 195, 236, 273, 70, 74, 239, 66, 121, 268, 245, 119, 247, 153, 144, 153, 187, 270, 253, 195, 167, 230, 232, 119, 66, 70, 261, 153, 256, 264, 236, 144, 266, 273, 158, 247, 144, 68, 273, 121, 167, 282, 195, 70, 158, 284, 266, 286, 236, 288, 68, 286, 68, 288]],[1],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288])
```

```
Automaton("det",266,4,[[1, 127, 50, 50, 115, 249, 50, 8, 257, 10, 151, 12, 13, 14, 81, 78, 34, 106, 137, 107, 21, 22, 82, 89, 71, 43, 43, 62, 63, 63, 44, 10, 179, 171, 214, 265, 206, 38, 137, 152, 21, 151, 71, 22, 41, 41, 47, 13, 49, 50, 50, 210, 50, 210, 116, 90, 64, 49, 207, 207, 207, 62, 232, 64, 64, 89, 151, 236, 236, 70, 71, 236, 116, 260, 128, 75, 13, 38, 77, 133, 14, 82, 13, 13, 77, 235, 64, 64, 231, 206, 138, 91, 91, 206, 90, 264, 137, 169, 10, 10, 41, 71, 232, 228, 232, 21, 21, 107, 106, 110, 111, 266, 256, 114, 114, 116, 251, 251, 116, 114, 114, 111, 266, 260, 122, 182, 127, 128, 129, 213, 132, 132, 129, 49, 49, 138, 138, 138, 249, 71, 43, 43, 210, 235, 183, 214, 132, 265, 206, 138, 232, 64, 64, 153, 153, 64, 152, 152, 82, 236, 236, 82, 116, 116, 64, 207, 266, 64, 231, 169, 171, 250, 227, 70, 175, 175, 176, 10, 47, 178, 178, 110, 111, 266, 260, 122, 266, 127, 213, 49, 49, 152, 257, 153, 257, 90, 90, 183, 250, 264, 62, 228, 229, 82, 82, 206, 64, 266, 249, 249, 249, 242, 213, 214, 64, 116, 114, 114, 50, 50, 236, 236, 261, 115, 152, 251, 8, 228, 229, 229, 231, 232, 237, 235, 235, 236, 237, 235, 235, 235, 235, 235, 235, 242, 242, 242, 115, 251, 249, 250, 116, 116, 116, 207, 64, 265, 266, 257, 256, 266, 264, 261, 260, 264, 265, 266], [1, 125, 1, 114, 114, 121, 115, 3, 23, 19, 13, 15, 230, 28, 201, 202, 16, 84, 123, 103, 105, 208, 114, 84, 172, 199, 199, 119, 83, 83, 123, 170, 16, 31, 27, 26, 25, 104, 102, 23, 28, 13, 120, 208, 48, 103, 19, 230, 239, 1, 114, 218, 115, 219, 82, 140, 23, 208, 204, 216, 216, 119, 174, 119, 119, 84, 13, 115, 115, 50, 120, 50, 82, 204, 262, 79, 230, 104, 203, 85, 28, 114, 230, 230, 203, 3, 23, 119, 96, 96, 96, 123, 102, 140, 208, 3, 200, 200, 98, 97, 103, 120, 119, 120, 119, 28, 105, 103, 105, 54, 3, 23, 141, 1, 250, 50, 82, 114, 50, 1, 250, 3, 3, 219, 219, 125, 54, 263, 124, 124, 27, 124, 223, 208, 239, 25, 208, 208, 120, 120, 217, 217, 217, 120, 120, 142, 142, 141, 140, 140, 174, 174, 174, 204, 216, 23, 119, 23, 250, 114, 114, 250, 162, 162, 159, 205, 159, 159, 208, 123, 170, 1, 219, 50, 208, 208, 123, 177, 177, 19, 170, 173, 172, 172, 199, 199, 23, 186, 185, 184, 184, 23, 120, 216, 23, 140, 208, 120, 1, 3, 119, 120, 114, 114, 250, 239, 119, 3, 121, 3, 120, 219, 212, 212, 23, 50, 1, 250, 1, 114, 50, 114, 219, 114, 23, 114, 3, 120, 114, 114, 208, 119, 125, 121, 3, 50, 54, 120, 3, 120, 121, 3, 120, 218, 219, 217, 114, 114, 3, 1, 250, 250, 250, 253, 252, 173, 172, 120, 125, 3, 3, 219, 219, 3, 54, 3], [1, 1, 249, 249, 6, 1, 1, 247, 7, 130, 167, 17, 11, 66, 33, 33, 131, 136, 10, 32, 150, 9, 112, 36, 149, 112, 149, 56, 167, 37, 181, 130, 35, 147, 139, 51, 139, 11, 10, 234, 147, 37, 148, 113, 136, 136, 146, 24, 249, 1, 1, 249, 249, 249, 139, 6, 238, 127, 134, 238, 134, 9, 148, 238, 134, 167, 36, 50, 249, 247, 73, 249, 51, 139, 112, 167, 76, 76, 11, 167, 80, 73, 67, 66, 66, 135, 58, 58, 112, 139, 233, 100, 100, 2, 6, 95, 10, 32, 130, 130, 99, 94, 94, 56, 149, 150, 147, 150, 136, 51, 51, 51, 7, 51, 51, 51, 7, 6, 139, 139, 139, 2, 58, 134, 139, 7, 1, 112, 112, 249, 238, 238, 112, 249, 127, 238, 233, 238, 1, 149, 112, 149, 249, 135, 7, 139, 238, 51, 139, 238, 112, 238, 233, 234, 234, 134, 234, 190, 112, 50, 249, 73, 139, 51, 238, 134, 51, 134, 148, 32, 147, 145, 145, 145, 258, 259, 180, 130, 146, 189, 189, 51, 51, 134, 134, 139, 2, 1, 249, 127, 249, 191, 191, 191, 188, 188, 188, 188, 198, 197, 196, 196, 195, 187, 187, 139, 233, 134, 127, 127, 127, 49, 249, 139, 243, 211, 211, 211, 210, 210, 210, 210, 95, 209, 241, 209, 126, 117, 117, 9, 112, 112, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 49, 49, 127, 127, 127, 249, 249, 249, 7, 7, 1, 247, 51, 139, 211, 134, 134, 51, 51, 7, 7, 2, 126, 145, 139, 247, 51, 51], [1, 51, 3, 4, 4, 7, 7, 50, 73, 61, 11, 12, 40, 109, 101, 93, 45, 18, 19, 20, 21, 64, 161, 29, 193, 118, 193, 65, 11, 42, 19, 59, 30, 46, 163, 164, 163, 40, 39, 57, 46, 42, 246, 60, 18, 21, 61, 158, 72, 50, 51, 53, 53, 3, 55, 55, 57, 246, 156, 64, 65, 64, 155, 64, 65, 11, 29, 68, 69, 236, 160, 72, 73, 55, 157, 11, 154, 154, 40, 11, 46, 160, 225, 192, 192, 86, 87, 88, 157, 118, 155, 19, 39, 74, 161, 239, 92, 92, 166, 254, 20, 144, 88, 240, 65, 109, 108, 21, 21, 50, 50, 73, 73, 50, 247, 236, 73, 161, 72, 3, 5, 54, 86, 239, 3, 51, 50, 64, 64, 161, 165, 64, 157, 161, 245, 165, 60, 64, 51, 240, 161, 240, 4, 144, 51, 55, 57, 73, 55, 57, 157, 157, 155, 57, 64, 156, 64, 87, 118, 160, 161, 248, 163, 164, 165, 168, 164, 168, 60, 19, 108, 3, 3, 72, 64, 60, 19, 194, 194, 61, 59, 247, 247, 193, 193, 5, 74, 7, 69, 244, 69, 156, 240, 65, 74, 74, 246, 143, 219, 86, 88, 144, 222, 222, 226, 72, 60, 239, 52, 54, 143, 239, 72, 72, 215, 221, 219, 224, 219, 220, 221, 222, 239, 220, 215, 222, 54, 160, 160, 161, 64, 64, 160, 68, 236, 236, 236, 160, 239, 240, 244, 245, 246, 69, 72, 161, 51, 160, 50, 50, 248, 118, 226, 255, 255, 248, 248, 160, 160, 245, 245, 72, 72, 236, 236, 236]],[12],[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266])
```

4.

```
Automaton("det",9,4,[[1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 5, 2], [1, 1, 2, 8, 2, 2, 1, 6, 2], [1, 1, 2, 7, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],[4],[2, 6])
```

```
Automaton("det",100,4,[[0, 1, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 34, 36, 37, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 68, 69, 71, 72, 73, 78, 79, 81, 84, 85, 86, 90, 93, 94, 95, 98, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 35, 36, 37, 38, 40, 41, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 59, 60, 61, 64, 66, 67, 69, 70, 71, 75, 76, 78, 80, 81, 84, 85, 86, 87, 89, 92, 93, 95, 96, 97, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 26, 28, 29, 30, 32, 34, 35, 38, 40, 41, 45, 47, 49, 50, 53, 56, 57, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 71, 72, 73, 74, 76, 77, 79, 81, 82, 83, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [ 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 32, 33, 34, 35, 39, 40, 42, 43, 46, 47, 51, 54, 55, 59, 60, 61, 63, 64, 67, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 82, 84, 85, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],[39],[1, 2, 5, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 24, 25, 28, 30, 31, 33, 35, 37, 41, 42, 43, 44, 49, 50, 52, 53, 57, 61, 63, 65, 66, 67, 69, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 85, 86, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 100])
```

5.

A [pair of equivalent DFAs](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GNTvfXCCt7/)

## Non-equivalent DFAs

```
Automaton("det",100,4,[[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 13, 15, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 27, 29, 30, 31, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 40, 41, 42, 45, 46, 47, 48, 56, 57, 60, 62, 64, 65, 69, 70, 73, 74, 76, 80, 81, 82, 84, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 92, 93, 94, 95, 97, 98, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 11, 12, 13, 16, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 30, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 42, 47, 49, 52, 53, 54, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 68, 69, 71, 72, 75, 76, 78, 81, 82, 84, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 21, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 33, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 41, 43, 46, 50, 51, 53, 55, 56, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 70, 73, 74, 76, 77, 78, 80, 83, 86, 87, 89, 91, 92, 93, 95, 98, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 13, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 35, 36, 37, 40, 42, 46, 47, 48, 50, 51, 53, 54, 56, 58, 60, 61, 63, 64, 65, 66, 68, 70, 71, 72, 74, 75, 76, 79, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 89, 90, 91, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 99, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],[52],[1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 32, 34, 35, 36, 37, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44, 46, 47, 49, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 60, 61, 62, 66, 67, 70, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 86, 87, 89, 90, 92, 94, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100])
```

```
Automaton("det",100,4,[[0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 31, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 40, 42, 43, 44, 46, 48, 49, 51, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 69, 71, 72, 73, 76, 78, 79, 80, 83, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 95, 96, 99, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29, 30, 31, 32, 34, 35, 36, 37, 40, 41, 42, 43, 45, 47, 48, 50, 51, 53, 56, 57, 59, 60, 62, 63, 64, 71, 72, 73, 75, 76, 77, 79, 80, 83, 85, 86, 87, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 96, 98, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [ 0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 16, 18, 21, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 32, 34, 35, 36, 37, 39, 40, 41, 42, 45, 47, 48, 50, 51, 52, 53, 56, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 72, 73, 75, 76, 78, 79, 80, 82, 84, 85, 86, 89, 90, 93, 94, 97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 16, 18, 21, 22, 23, 24, 28, 30, 31, 32, 34, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 42, 44, 45, 47, 48, 51, 52, 53, 56, 57, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 67, 70, 74, 76, 83, 84, 86, 88, 90, 91, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],[17],[1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 16, 18, 19, 22, 23, 27, 28, 29, 30, 32, 35, 36, 38, 40, 41, 42, 44, 46, 47, 48, 50, 51, 53, 54, 55, 62, 64, 66, 71, 72, 74, 75, 76, 79, 83, 86, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100])
```

```
Automaton("det",100,4,[[2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 20, 21, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 32, 35, 36, 37, 40, 42, 43, 44, 46, 47, 48, 50, 53, 54, 55, 57, 58, 59, 62, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 69, 72, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 4, 5, 8, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 29, 30, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 60, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 70, 71, 72, 74, 75, 77, 78, 79, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 93, 95, 96, 97, 98, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 23, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 37, 38, 40, 41, 42, 45, 47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 56, 59, 61, 63, 64, 65, 68, 70, 72, 73, 74, 76, 77, 78, 80, 81, 85, 86, 87, 88, 92, 93, 94, 96, 98, 99, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 30, 31, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 42, 43, 44, 45, 48, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 60, 62, 64, 65, 66, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 74, 75, 76, 77, 79, 84, 86, 91, 92, 93, 96, 97, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],[46],[1, 2, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 15, 17, 18, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 27, 28, 29, 30, 32, 33, 35, 36, 37, 39, 41, 42, 44, 45, 47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 54, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 73, 75, 76, 77, 79, 80, 81, 82, 85, 86, 88, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98])
```

```
Automaton("det",100,4,[[0, 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 33, 35, 36, 37, 39, 43, 44, 45, 46, 49, 50, 51, 52, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 62, 63, 67, 68, 70, 72, 73, 74, 76, 77, 78, 81, 82, 83, 85, 87, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 27, 29, 30, 31, 32, 34, 35, 36, 39, 40, 42, 45, 46, 47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 55, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 66, 67, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 77, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 86, 87, 88, 89, 92, 94, 96, 98, 99, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 20, 21, 23, 30, 31, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 42, 43, 44, 46, 47, 48, 50, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 60, 61, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 70, 71, 75, 76, 77, 80, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 91, 92, 94, 98, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 31, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 41, 43, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 57, 58, 59, 62, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 71, 72, 75, 76, 77, 80, 81, 82, 83, 86, 87, 88, 91, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],[45],[2, 4, 6, 7, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 24, 25, 27, 28, 29, 30, 37, 39, 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 67, 71, 72, 76, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 91, 92, 94, 95, 99, 100])
```

## Score

This question is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) and [restricted-time](/questions/tagged/restricted-time).  Your code must be able to run all the test cases in less than a minute on TIO.  Your code only needs to output something Truthy or Falsey depending on whether the two DFAs are equivalent or not.

[[GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/) has a library function for this but I am not aware of any other languages that do.  Please feel free to use whatever your language does provide however.]

Comment: "list of initial states"? There's usually exactly one initial state, and all examples have one initial state.

Comment: @aschepler Yes . I have added a comment to make it clear you can assume there will be exactly one initial state.

Comment: Wait, it's currently a two-part code golf: (parse the GAP syntax) + (test if the two DFAs are equivalent). I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: Well, GAPs `Automata` package has `AreEquivAut`, but the description doesn't sound fast for big automata: check that corresponding minimal automata are isomorphic.

Comment: @Bubbler I updated the question to hopefully remove the parsing issue.

Comment: what can parsing include from the following: removing redundant information (Type, Size, Alphabet); switching to 0-indexing; swapping the initial state with state 0; turning the list of accepting states to a boolean vector; adding an extra fake state for "no transition" transitions?

Comment: @ngn You can remove what you like, reorder it and change the type of brackets. You can't swap the initial state or turn the accepting states into a boolean vector or add an extra fake state.  I wouldn't mind 0-indexing except the 0 transition has a special meaning.

Comment: tests as json: https://pastebin.com/raw/082Tgrww

Comment: While GAP allows holes in lists and therefore in matrices, they hit the reader of this challenge rather unprepared. When your test input only has zeros, it's enough to explain what they mean. Also, `AreEquivAut` is a library function, not a builtin.

Comment: @ChristianSievers I don't think I have any test examples with holes. If I do that is my mistake.

Comment: @Anush Your description of the input format mentions holes.

Comment: can we assume that the alphabets of the two dfa-s are of the same size?

Comment: Applied fixes. @ngn no you can’t assume that.

Comment: @Anush then it would be nice to add at least one test with different alphabet sizes

Comment: @ngn I changed my mind. You can assume the alphabets are of the same size. It's not an interesting detail of the challenge.

Answer (score 8):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 101 bytes

```
{a:&,/~=\:/+/'x[2]=\:'!'#'*'*x:+@[;0;0,']'x;n:#**|*x;~#a^a^{?y@<y:y,/x@\:y}[,/'+\:'/(n;1)**x]/,n/x 1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7Vvbrh03cn2fr9iBg8hHVqDmvVudIP4PjQbjFwfBBAowmAcJjv3rTq21imx2731kY3ySIMjg7At3N1msKhZXXdjnT//48V8//vzz9@9@@O7dP7x5@9M///7d22/evvr0Pn6w5qu/e/XVq9evXn9698237/dlX968@vDq0/7x3VevX//n60/7T19994fv/vDDv3z@9p8@v/v85u2nb3//7vOP79@8ffWNDX779cc9PL1@/enD2zcf3366hR9//su7H/7@/eef/vzu@9un/Y//8af96z9@/92//fv@af@8//npw4@/@8v7r7/@OtzSLd@WPdwiWk972tX43e120@2gm097xK0n3AkfNHrhqHJbSMFbo13Zjsf1px20Mm6Rvk0Qb/izS3skLbt9aRW0wFe4TI6b9RYWfrVbsHbGz7Ci0fir4LI11z0ZSWsEfRW07FvNFS819Vn2bDzhmtFIuiRK3q8d10LaizG53QJ55cwJPzOpRRLIPqjdmpRAJVNHoLmR7zD1rhy8jmWIPqFGNPuM7BT5quKFeodcG3/jr5DjZJ@6UnZcjmiCASlsUU@94uhWnEeRJ1@ZXFZ@unqf9rL/kjTsd127jXfb9B3zLa63tOBCsldl23vwI224hH7llo2diAH20y7mxrtmbAtHVtzNFRetc2TnnDAKtyr6Y7ipdDHjoCGB1dUbkXqJxY0qmYiZr9VvubHxinoa9STOCibQqLzhom5Z25izlxrWR6Psp18p/LQrac8yV@hu80a0lTOWK14puBXH4rdCv2KfefFP0oLQGhWoNhubA36aDqCbArLeuUuCV0M3qFmvZYc1yd6Kf5s20i0aGdq/tZNZStOdMEy0cr7kCscczQfh4gq5bRBUVdAH7ZXrtZADLpz0mjgQd7Gsv24vlbGdoEpbPddjckOCahoNidZl2sFqc8UgTcWktshmSAc/2Rc5d2bKMu3VRMyLmQxhqsW@jaiQJpGNMvFTzvxwaCQJchBpAlvnxl/Y7euNeg3EHy4pqKxc6gU7yr5tPlmN7nAi392CNl5uNOLG8YmEC67z02ZyOAEAAG5pf3g1vsyowezGH1Bv1gf@pFTYx@iCqdHC1y3uRBQsIYdynRK3ehD6PlrFxBmwQq4bkCC7GYPDoCIs3Xzrpu1pb/v/mMFcMG8CmakZpRbinW9CrnBJV0wanSshDg3zBaYy8y0mSbitBvTWMJls8bFjb9sqKAJYGRkTEz@5LReMCzAGLL4ROyYEuNgFkQ4JnhU3oJ2KGYIZvN2x2St0DgSCKQFfsBJY0MShlZyFtoC70CK@KjnkxBghirhivza4b7ux2g27ZDf8ikkTtigeNqO4bZQCc7hsEd82g9orBaRkxhKIYERN/Bnp6SrFYLcCy2vkKULbCesdxvDVb5nyV8lbG2WDaiI6AZ84QATYtmumnUna3jE0vyGtZdcg9i62fZEWwVfF7j5GcUq0DYQozwrnF6mRNpjCXfSOGeaySCnwNWAKFGFD2BeweSi6cK0wBOoEtxtwurFdpUkuQ6UM1qR@nWQEszAP7BNjnvfARo2DSScCvUfjktwFcbcehlLUIYoGWGxBa@QcpuMOqGCShm3pGoFtYJbs3He7xHWsMPSBcdDJsQOg4BZEHHdqokhcVowyMao0U4rmwpxYCaNBXZtN4xqEHAYF2EwkhhnB9FrE8dpExX7XlT8rotPJ2femozZdeRq@uDGGyHexQe9cg0OyUTeurNFWjFqzd9jYYbPNBuTDhsEmAh1rM4Jo@h0RXALwsSPmORmhRaceaKBB3XPjnYAYbBE4ZBJj0@nCMCpjtlBtGexW56QBuRGFA37bMbuThSyRA8Kaxeu68Y6kYeABtC9@IS6BvHQRI76rOOqcdbYihEMMAyfg9wknGwlyDTEjXMAijZB0xTagbsluoe4jXERwdhiepa6UQQCDnfAsMKzLu9BOQht6RO@Qj1FgDZwDoDHZYLP3CdQstOqKxiSwOuzdkCgQfpagXtBzQTySD0VuXBLQTYtrQOtHyftIZ6@B2HpMh8udaF1oJ0M1JZNTTkbjPMj0tYmO5bFusF9wD9apOueRHGFI1fWu2rFem8MKVmAoKA31S4phpFR9InJ31UKNMTr1IF2SChYMSNZEkauVxFFsk9VwNYP6rq7d6xLGviDJuS2kj/6DDminIcWeR4jN8NKbjMZT8HgnMz804LN1KuXoPjqb17H1sh1pHQydTM@2mmaNxj90znDc9pg5hI3tsCwgFxZlIIHhewiEeLQQpZ9nE@0AxuHajCl63owbAUPsLr5ydl8of1g3ksVPa6KDARu0aliNe43X2QIcLM4uKSIQXKMzTTegvMIvoMtGKcMG@1o4E7yDYZC0EReoqYFoJDYsrgX2hhxc9DpYkY9LogGYR@AYY9cO5oTYaZ2lEmuwEMmPWaHZGEV16ATfTrurKq3jVt9oIkpi0HaJChh8LlNIzMtQB12UCxMZVa0UM2aPRzgUY7bBG4UCWczGrV5oAvK0xce7guxNElpdzkYN9o5QpqyAYnfVySAooi14XQ8ma/G4ot6axMMKuSV1A6li2KhBFU2G15JGpzKIg0rooq7RNeZtBElQf/GAqU4qI8yEYw3Yt2@c2JyqWzp4kWnEfhXBcR/vyy/1Tdd8XtLOm9s5KXgPCDbmcq6My72MYooFZqOpqopSyQ1tpK4W7se59@hrDszCHwQuplhTtfncjNG2xUw3FgOK2MYMDaE4oG2BzwQcYi9xXEBkgiQQX/Uyn6gHwygEj8z0AAal37CuVYFplbk3GC60vUg7SXMw4t3Egog1chkAFMiHyLALktUXIIGAHikSvgKHY1bmGHVc4mQmWIRw1oZ/QhPKAoxAVswDo2foJH8WGOAmMiR@fUxZRQoBIMJUQ1/XEyIQKMAUAX24gOhIB3coZEHsiDA7eGSbqTUMJGlwyzJDExXuVblVRIOLiDGdkXywTNgpCCC6mnqYBsDM5mprsEBARZPXRvy3dMYoT2eoq9EIoAd1DTdfqXPwzrWVRFCkdYZbzG3MBv11dbtssUqeKm4pAEPq7E6TIkZmGkFv2RMJNOkb04FdFxm8tXyoFNmM2x3VCEcLpwuXuKjnRq7ZcaVCsH5kvYtffImbq4QxRl@3yP7aVpIoUTMUI9UBTZEIt4qyIJ6XuGwIC8Sdb4u4@ijsTjCslAs/@bX@79XJ0sNSGQOEiIKDWabhF6KQBtdbWNsA8McOQVwxVRoq9zeqEpFhSmblo6LEYN7ILHRlnQG7PiFeNPtYe3VhZRXAtvZG7DJD8yyhoUbCBGRxLIuOZ9nzBm280MM1qi14upS475U2eRQO9QXPA6PnRUz/M8OjEKtXXFYWWZRNBeVNyXEjedkFGQ08RPIcm2mul0H65kdATDPx/LMsl83vxQ6mxKuXaBb3MFFFEYbzHkQTVFff9QsDLpYQmJzlc4KG2ItYuxBv6T1Zv8kOtFUAgKICUjUWYoJKOVtyrCgOu41BSGDetijsXqI2/5KZu/WwTHmB4jLkbdHzNiITw@d6FBkYiS2qVcCcWcnJqjNE1W8iC6PbQAJsVIXzKsgo9G4HVqKEjVwGpQYWZLKjYxVCZvn@yGQqMGiK3OqZQRO3fGnMlVhsqIIDFBuQBxEOavfrTWBTHceayg2R8UZm9IFYgOkCgjIgNfAUZQkEfWsSQAAt6b4bIaFXq2GLOpVgoqr9uaqC4pbUEcIo2gSwz8Vtc2kOEivTBGNNRwe@fbn7u58E38HlWlStBQmoRjFRI6XMwwlm/MeBCRbav7DPzIwqj1NkDHpDd7ZuwIwMZkBSC1cdNpQoV6WituQsboIRmHKSiNFLztAmQlhSo014lAoI0S94M4YxPQrBK0sOGBCMKlE6CEgIqQM@uLTYloSPLL5oKsGhpF/3vuQ5aotN8KFQI@odNz9LEmisIwgdC8MdA3RZtVswrK8IOw8NCjtGPIY3rMkVCi6CtAn9YAlq7aoSdASZv/FKFCkHcvCwTtixnhXiQtILR8VRLlDpRb3E723plWFOUpVI@DZexeoihqpyguN9YEXNJ127rbmI9M/BsyBblfWACUJFh4nmEDHDRHn8Jlzozc1WwoCJrk3aAax5QgAiRXUNZUeKZUYJnKFEntF0s4linqc5YfNTbOLbOqAVp3RZzokOz2sS2AZeS4dfZKl9o0tN6oz1ZP6PJeIhppxl9NOn4IXYRTWBRQdexNbNeWSZPShPhi0BUJPjenb89iQCPic4DzoQorflUSmmKYtWOxM@m2YK9BjptuoUK/Qob@FVacUIIgDgS0pwRlDrch/EExRmOZJpePbATEoBgnRXstPNPGIvnTO3LF3i3BhLOhzEwheDg8xjOPom14UfXp@ONBZ3bc3PLHRNYUH0EGHRm@5a76FWCR6TW53MRZXvqHfxQilzkc1n9mUn4728Nm40vXvAkDxgOAwo9jOd4rEBzzcli3hyvVOUW5r0fDBI68FRHq27D9/c@9P4hp7DUDuNbXMT4Fc6U156vFacrtfX49J7TrN5PME4L3dq7uf7O6lI0tVACuW08ox7kx7FcFiqN/1qfH5kURjGkwDb9YnPQyhK7A8WIM5T0T75SRb8NDymYjh4JYRkiNSLl9A3leJ0ZrDoFCirKwtVyaNOHcvBEPN2m7lUcQXcIhSiH2KItPJ7I5n@i0xUGktWjoSIJU88RPZBAK8nSnBWtqBXZeYLJ2CsIy1Y1ZtpavJQXQ/@IHqUPhhHLwjlEdznWz/ggxF4DRqSIfXgq83NKpb8zTKgAnEex3iwr2qYgsB1/KajSl6t54n8vBrSGB/@SRrr4g8SY2jWgvRv@Dc8UyT9tdTXr@u3lwmyHi1gClDGu4eWDM2hGqQJiIrWzYUOPpkEDocs@GaQ7m8G79ObQXrzoN1zeAb57Vgh0CWY6T2ZDuNlxuz9vZzemyqFDK8XFY@UVrXbNtZB4Dq/PEyY5pxtlruKNti1Hw4FdBtoUAOm6yWV7Cays4Oel0K3IiMNnj4DaRdVoSynyeWUQFcVMpHoIeEJqj3z@JD1dJZ8Eh8GOjIxPoeTWBjKfI4JiUXlo20gqWJSiz2TTnglJtIFY3RGUnv67AX17LPGzXNphsN18WyaaaIfPaqYnFkfyOqEdElpWzySag3wCuYGjpuLm3RmEMf5Cl1UvvHEeiEnVNnq4bEWsbFWW1QMYtyeVNbVQ4RGhhUOAijHeKjKVNYlbV43VbW4sg/jLD9PR22CrOiQojQXnsFlf/MnyVGLq4tZO431kjav3l65ShKMTxwqmta1TcWxysKa0sTmaTCkQzmjF3p5OFC7qnAna1WznAhWwM8MmNJGprKYTW4SxZWs3lgUntXqcD14QpzvE@Pkv9lPBCiwhO6q9qJhHe/gcyopPhLhuum0VmBT@0aNfiTC3Ju5cPF8eR3ziUTpjB@TPe0h7n@rY/3/rGPlv9Wy/m/Xsk6Pw@k55KTwEo8G@pPJK58IDwgx/UpTeNKfFdSjw/3vacdj4tXLWUoeTrCQ@3PdQoN7KLjgQHYE@MLe/9KWv@x3bfax07W7w7GpsZfHLub@XX7rHyv9meh4wcbiz0I@gMTmT167EiYYdD38egAc0Jc74g24E8qtHd9mZNs6oHU0A479Nj3IGE6eYlZF66qQHmZLiN0XDPELpZbI6bzoXwD5GeEF79sE7BdUfx7SX0YJV2eZ/fmxkyl013jyiHKE0R9N9ahY6z0WW/K3L3q12Jf83oddHNiL/T3tadsFMHqK9rkoIfSdMLZBf5b9hAKyAFl864KXydDvZb@48@LB2xccuWng8m82wf/Rpun/TLyap2087@FtYn6KZg4sm1GMRuyYlfvTP8thrwfb@S7@mHluL4Vcz5gvRJ/3bv1SWJeWuwgu9r07gOphdDZv2QFUz8kf/GGiF9qmz0gfr87s3npn073EtekunA2@hY@8sfgTYI9V0vyxgROECb7TBNxhwu71ZffvMAA4tHWSvp2hqzwK6Wfzj5PhD@lzf/5txrDuuI8Qfezm7ZmwfNjEBb1fCMye9hL5PxjyY24L8z@KaT88l@DEc2pz@T@W2rfH2ZUf5kBsa8uvwLZ8Vkh8AO0jUOuL2s6B2iyPVvcskj/aeAlQBj7XHpqEu@Bstu3ZN9cp6UqPNnoZD0v/9xj2ZV2HS7pPWS9xankUqpY7K6/9ma4pPD3Ev6xlemTW2t31JXFu7/87OmfxA9/XybP9emO@iB5d@l9Iw2c1DEOI0wbfpii9vdj6B/@/1Tt0H@KP9V8fpCcn95Yn2SfBj2W/w3U9zwQnP7bt@hjEXtTqD0QLbQ9fkP@w/8vaa@HXRxB2QfbSA5v6CMfTozDsUTGFkdgy/ocrXQ22w5YDVrnLJC5eKN1xPJKnAVV3PviILMuURvx1xaGXCEuy4ul0l16PdGqEIF8uqj2XUOa70ORu@17985xmnDUzp5UvF6DsixvD9kxisU0R@n2K3c5WPCeYUkHtXmuKUE9eeA7HwskOTnnVyydVD/Pr7RyXdKO4xun1rIjnDGQuu6zPFBrmmsul4HIfumnTEOlOHu03A9zTnuuuMtWcYc7y3xVaDnBIZ1cWznB@vyPaZBQPK8rpmeisp53PgMNUP3tUK3i4xX8x6djOZaOH@/uCee15K58z6PbihZIHVj2W8@GBwnPh2LDfMoXWQ@7yTLI1YuxL@eQLMfbai2Yvv809OLu450vZjMB23cZjDz/0dM9t4HCF91O9sPWI7KG/G577RTPPXUbwoGb28GjpEqbeaeQooj6sms6b4Lkq4qyLYQwD8MODDfECUVoue68ln6qGs4O7x7V7LHvo48sX66ijlFifPQs7RW2nYO3n/wI)

the argument `x` is a pair of dfa-s.

a dfa is `(TransitionTable;InitialState;FinalStates)`.

we prepend 0 to all rows in both transition tables. this way we can use 0-indexing, and state0 can act as a tarpit state to handle "no transition" transitions.

consider a new dfa whose states are the cartesian product of those of dfa0 and dfa1.
when state `i` from dfa0 is paired with state `j` from dfa1, the resulting state is labelled `(i*n)+j` where `n` is the number of states in dfa1.
`a` is the list of states in the new dfa for which one of the original states was final and the other was not.

we combine the initial states of dfa0 and dfa1 using the formula `(i*n)+j`.
starting there, we compute the set of states in the new automaton that are reachable through its transitions.
we test if that set is disjoint from `a` and return a boolean result.

Comment: Ah ok. On my phone I just see `ok 8 times in the output section of TIO.  Which part is too hard in that case?

Comment: @Anush `ok in my output means that the actual result matches the expected result

Comment: ok....:). What did your mean by "too hard"?

Comment: @Anush it was a mistake of mine. i thought you were talking about different alphabet sizes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 431 program + 5 interpreter = 436 bytes

```
m-->member.
g(A):-read_string(user_input,"\n",[],_,S),term_string(A,S).
f(I,T,S,R):-select(S,T,R),m(I,S),!;S=[I],R=T.
x(S,R)-->[N],{nth1(S,R,N);S=0,N=0}.
x(A,B,C,D)-->x(A,C),x(B,D).
c(_,_,[]).
c(M,E,[A,B|R]):-M=[S,T,C,D],(m(A,C)->m(B,D);\+m(B,D)),f(A,E,X,F),plus(B,N,0),(m(N,X)->c(M,E,R);f(N,F,Y,G),union(X,Y,Z),(P=..[x,A,B]),foldl(P,S,T,Q,R),c(M,[Z|G],Q)).
r:-g(a(A,[B],C)),g(a(D,[E],F)),(c([A,D,C,F],[],[B,E])->R=y;R=n),print(R).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7Vpbjx3FEX73r3B42qOMrb5N9wyWI2EwiAcsWPNAOBxZBBbHkr1Ga1sQhfx2Z@r7qqp7djeR8pYHP5zRXLrr3tVVX59fr16/fP383pvfXrx//@revb@8unj1t4ur@3een31y@Pje1cWPPz978/bqxeXzs3dvLq6evbj89d3b6aMfLj@ajqfp2fT0ML29uHplYz7ZXty/88vZl9O309PpfKPw5uLlxU9vz55uL84P06vtyzblTw@ePjx@eZrOH357/87vZzJyY318cpr@efn271FeTE8O26AwPXkY/iVjPpkeTZ9On8k4efj0MP1@9mh7vn/np7NnmyDHE26/mh5Px23sH@enjflXD4/CeJt3ms5eYdqmIeY9@OHPvDlMv2wfHk/fTZ8fpl9fvnuzvX0yhYNMeDJ9t00g1fPDg1@2F59Pf52@OEzvLl@8vjz7bnv4fhv59cP794@/Txvf00bu9cufX559PQnnb0RpmX/8/o8vTtM3h03Iq4/vPT/7ceN5fHTaBDpM8vTZdHx82iTYiP10tinw2Sb05yex8fHR9Pi0SXH@8B8Pzh9ebjJuln57dn64//79j2fHY5ru1uluDNuvbL/lxmOat9863c15@23fyvatbPel8nnO@/G3za2BY3Hfprstbr/tW9vul@1@2Wgscr/NWbexayGfdSGfGIRgEOox6qsolxRIKCaRIjW5rNdkylHfGtcoosSC7zJQyAn3WFYOEBGrMJtlNIjNMmXevscq5GpWUlW1iC1QldgSb6rqQ9Ew3xjhtbwRXaMoHxf5Lu/lu78WO8Q1maCrMFpXVR783TAJd8JcHxc1D60iooMsptesr1KcXbjVJojCKTYVPcGpYsSU4khu8RHi5sXsJXrDLDBzwvCSfbZR5KN8EEvvjdXnxNa/qyOK@0XI5yKX2ZwD@cVDKe9oUCA8lmhWEIapJDVsG2XHKMxMBXEczLilmuxggwgXIRCYdOOswYH58BJUEz@mueljNf/Q2VXVlif6zhklaIZwlfHQlkMgaU2jPk4Wnk2iENWIpsayC93ZRiajCm1atIhwZfJuAAiDv1glZbcsAhUCFNe3LyN8RXzBrKAC2@5WM5zXojHFAAlZWIIRBRqiejUbz7PJAYngcKFKV8qKxAcYaIh1mYUVKAwgD3RcZtNPwpx05V1d9FVdTtPdoxhH@AglccPuMUGOLfMFPotWIkyR7Lbdi14I52H6bXMl0GQu7jf@oobct4V0ltLHrjp2lewi9AIyAlIFyMsjmGFZ4J3wikkESVjq18WC/Dl1xpGLK9pcEQIDoqhkYnKpCgc@OT9EbC1Kq4rnZUQXt4k/4NQmH5Ffu3zODTZIOjsuxTRbVh1gRoC44LPO/W0KUSXu9km4qyZ4V6GLn2AXsWOKeRzH3LsqF4YR5BHRuWAZCaZ1Suo4Kjeri5O80qxVVSeyMusOFEHM@V2zFxaCj2UQxzZ6BzNj2dGACtAU@yQEGTTqg6P6DO5yN4I9lgkyWMxqBryao42HF0X6BEG6d1b1Pdjl4Ea0oKHpOiHXo4HBspMFHzurGjRuBxvLEGhFQbiYdoR7FCTfWlNdufCgLlSlL1wbio351b52nw3hsXoOhpMHU@fRwar3uKbo26x7aPcZXAMVySuag0gX8YFNoRkbxkY2sVPbhzFjKNq0xd12W9Sk7vbsms3KF3MHymCZB70lq26UsY2J1PJy/4gUv4WGZDpJIpIFE7/LpiKRgQ1nmD7OlbJBokSykIyVJC/OlGCS5SOqw7kz6Uo2ka171ecYAhnFUClFFD3xJuoOjAfZUW8TyBhHqI3aRXRgEVb4PYKCjMJNKV75WPlTV@WHV/KEkbJXwHmyfWJM0898QKYMXUMyyniduqLcsrOq7G8xeFVDxRWLIagc2NAlfZtxU4D1G5kl5s7QDcqp0J9xWEeJrZbJRhabcUSApcHckAm2y8t1i6gWiGAzI6SC61IyZoN9cec8u/HzMo7oucVYkQE8OierN10OMW0qYbQrKw83QWKBv6iNUvEyl5RAYB11oC3ADJIw/c0ajlpzzU7PbS0X0rTooiTqlT4HPrKApNm6Myw8aR2Jurrs9KmzF6iVi4tKhDaEeQ/ZavoJCxi02RJp2cjleeQKwrEbSoysHvBH1Ohw8ewle927gMk57hzNaUNiSM15@YKFvBanqX9Dg9gJegyqS/YfXCzyLGtfrCTpQ2GQQQ4XflNIkqbsncJJQkE8uH8Ue8l@KmWTlKIrn4uscGmY043Z41QpTaT2Ro0svhOXSvVVSFIyithb2hhjI2lC2KBpxd4RUC5h80HSUEIRda@wZFlebxXJWEfJ@eiIMpYDkuU8fJd51dqwagu4YfHBt8HMnk0Atn2ryWkcmmoVkVCBU6iOboNiE5FL0REDv8BNVIIQi618Hd9TFLFKgmnkEZUHnuADZF1YCzJgKbOEt6olssXLKreq5wTmxaijj0FjJrugGx51Lawo9oRh3TiYw1pmZ9mAlgi9aPTOrqgjQIcsoRr6AlgGdJmwrL5COxOMAREFswyWFRYaKKLa3w8VI0Li1f3QsHCQUJvVdWhdwqAAzdDF7r4RihhKV6IqrOpUKMvIMkPAPTIRFVFpoyjwSXenWyVVM0M13agzW87idZOaJ7Glj3axYCfFZg6FLFDOTQYlWtn5CoCCLw86B5UXCjHUQMEmraol5yxqWEQNde0WnD3CmpuWRWsPlaRzLXmoIbLamKrnOmb3xH1jMYa29/I9IwVFpanhyzwtTgNJCeoZQIJXvFlOp@kY5bc9bQlryz1bTAEEbSg7V0USoxZwWVHFmcUcWoiFvTthF@3dsybdmS1easyMQFKDVq9JUdWiSblqn78wcwJpjSzBgLgWTdiVfb/snsiUQYvMRORTFpbsDqh0GwuyWVFY7NRpyOQaNQZ5Vs17wEqTVsVF0dpKrFMqDVlni0KeyIqZ7ZAE8TLAnIvijpL0Vt0VZIl4I96I8rL5D75VJN8vivfnlnpibzjomujARtbUqBCH969wUXTUJzl0QbyxaLkeU3UYeVHUWOGPaBBH9lSbHUsGwIA9PjtWRzTMsdueH9ErMpwdi5rDLfnRoVmCaIsj0MFrhmRgLjtjbza5oy2eFYN2BMQwia@UmyAL2gPudkG3PNZRxKiLb3TVUiSQTQAuRJejAdZr9sQ6@87XtMaNxF@CtaohWXIMRUGY3j1o023tA/CX5PgLUzybzLoDO9krBENRsSoJVxfDO5Mh1Cjf0RD0XImMpY2xoczar7bdzlSCoYyAPIkyF9@Hqm1GxYrGRNwjav2emAOL1u/MhnNTNIOgZ7WECdATAAUTZu1lYLM0XX1naAZ7JlaxReta1JFsyNE3YNvEJgagFP3Kki2NYmdibdeYNA935OzIjgOQgIJBVZaSFoN/PbaH/ClshDMWUvA1FFpPoYs236ID0l8eUpemw14aQdPoFkFvvhhZWNnK8qb0kVojUyk6@LVrgkjzGyQSiW@xOBzIuLQLXCLRgoxaKDZ4abzUnlQVVKuGRkng8VCKAmMdZrOSWSzzA2LQmDBIvS9DhrU3qFdYLvfalr9iJkB4I@6zmgcmYoatY3JlfCEVMbkWU4ExHD3X9q8@jVomyyT75KqFa7KLvCv604S6jO3WGAvMBkjCiyUCUOkRwImjZzS1js0CLoh4dxYkjeYoGBvOrnUwvabWaOtZNGOinXeZNWiIMbkuNw3rFmJhlqygd0PM/SQl690ahmNC8q/WqnsuW0yxYHJX67PHyy6V1nLDmb4o3D4s3aIjExIByy6LMpX2LNo8gV7LovN/uzCf2oXpZY5jFu1eYkBiOe7zIjNpdWsXz6ThWhKVNjpaKbAL52T6ZpZ20TrT2XaMZdzLRBTslsnr/@BIKRa2H9ai8OGZ7qplVLaJiCYFGREVlQWlFkVWZi4qSzJcmeikiqkb2tpV4oluNDwNwY49LPtmW3w79QYd9UJ0QYsyZaE16waQNFQYdUW3q2ZiRG7vmXViMmuoiEG/mY2FD2pE/ak1XVwcEHgdoX8XINxg5hhqvqiQhxaT5hPZdo0hSjYNLNPCV4B9UAFBjtSVCk8NWEsWOow33a4oF@bxHEHr0eCVS/Ozd/ugRWTymjLYhSWcXQavmfVS9mVioaynqckus596sfdfXTCPQFW0H1sM35tdepmZvczcxXfqf3OYvZgs@p4GMNHdu9QfBh89udOFoS1frSfsBFevFHWtjI6Mo3O5LlYPSL3JN3mG3krMnaGf5aYwzNpL40UpW5Iy8PCasF@yobvdoKQ534xBbfqyJbAxv1dqqkVos4YGHYIeVkteRCOavdPRjcsPde3sOPtfRVDNoWayhgOlBnoGdLizn9WuduBhB9zB/jRRbBrx/OwNlf1dBguorF2H3d4FioZ5sLRgqb7o3aqk@xtKWjWci2EZKI/LXtCko9H3VhUd/1QJnFAVHsO2Lfqi015sLmGr7I1tAMRQ9SzFrMv2MrAFRmtc7DDIO0M/wYRh0Ovrr914rCa/X/RMRptW/Y@Ct8x2sqANzTK@Yy2S/fAYX28EgLpi1ugyWm7JgehAqlgM9DsUNDLOfdPyED/diR2hLIo2a0M9j5fePrGdhaXRfaM@X9Zut@iSmMXizgS4Y3PrF7a@@wub2@YNr4OEbJbbLirAjtuEXfaRzVaS/W6/hBuX1Q5w2IUGg9EV@2h9@bp1b/t5vbmX6dqaaxY/WDfdyXFnxiEgG@0JgTpAXDxyNWnN0eC3YtNmW2exA3DY@IJh9YIygOY1CK7aqRQQHGAR0c4u@c8gPcxVzFtCA5ExgCmZzLKC5EDdkjb0KNkX5WU4e0sDFpf5ywrFzSSifxSoA/jmB7qli5bWjsaxYayh43EEhvyPRnYMWRSmLDYeGIeiMWkPy@l0P5VaqWdzs2U79U7jPw9YjhTSAO5R/Z9FYelNpEVU0@O72eBxtsLZTv2IuGr9RJxWdzMl4m0b4S63V/MDMztmrDqa7YH/DRAYqgptB/Fz63ZkV9Uv@opc1E2L26p2usstyNvij4uGiBmGkdCsEbVPq50@VD3JUKCoOYBG8zQuCT8V5OF2HXyAEcUCrFh1AJ/70TchsKTAF6SxAgrYcbGpiAX9w5f@PTA6olb@A7aW/R1nGEUazSzXPepHPHW8RBdJcbUdkFZX@8uXJe46JLDk/wogskc0bXbobRmlUaLzoOkoCc4F0nb5cCrw4VTg/@lUoHw4GvhwNPC/HA2cDnfe33v7/urf)

Pass arguments `-t r` to the interpreter to make `r` the top-level goal.

Expects the DFAs on standard input, one per line, but with the initial `'Automaton("det", Size, Alphabet'` shortened to just `'a('`. Outputs a single character to standard output: `y` if the DFAs are equivalent, or `n` if they are not.

A more legible version, with comments:

```
/* Parse a line from stdin as the term A.
   For this program, the term is expected to be a
   Deterministic Finite Automaton in the form
     a(TransitionTable, [Initial], Accepting). */
get(A) :- read_string(user_input, "\n", [], _, S), term_string(A,S).

/* Find the Set in SetOfSets which contains I, and remove it from the
   larger SetOfSets.
   Or if no such Set exists, use the one-element Set [I] instead, and
   leave SetOfSets unchanged. */
find(I, SetOfSets, Set, Rest) :-
  select(Set, SetOfSets, Rest), member(I, Set), !.
find(I, SetOfSets, [I], SetOfSets).

/* Look up the next state from a row of a transition table, or
   two next states from corresponding rows.
   A zero is the failure state and always stays at zero without lookup. */
next_state(0,_) --> [0].
next_state(State,Row) --> [Next], {nth1(State,Row,Next)}.
next_state(State1,State2,Row1,Row2) -->
    next_state(State1,Row1), next_state(State2,Row2).

/* Check if two DFAs are equivalent!

   Equiv is a set of sets of positive state indices from DFA1, negative
   state indices from DFA2, and 0 for a common failure state. After the
   algorithm has examined a pair of states, it makes sure one element
   in Equiv contains both those states for future iterations. All such
   states in one set are tentatively presumed to be equivalent.

   Require is an even-length list. Every pair of elements is a state from
   DFA1 followed by a state from DFA2, and it must be shown that the pair
   of states is equivalent:
     1. If one state is an accept state and the other is not, the DFAs
        are NOT equivalent.
     2. Otherwise, if both states are in the same member of Equiv, no
        further processing is needed for the current pair, since those
        states or related states were already seen.
     3. Otherwise, for each letter in the common alphabet, for equivalent
        DFAs it is necessary that the next states for the two DFAs are
        equivalent.
        3a. Add these pairs of next states to Require for the next iteration.
        3b. Merge sets containing the current states into a common set
            within Equiv for the next iteration.
     4. Repeat until an Accept mismatch is found or until Require is empty.
        If Require is empty, the DFAs are equivalent.
*/
check(_,_,[]).
check(Params,Equiv,[State1,State2|Require]) :-
  /* format("Equiv: ~p~nRequire: ~p~n", [Equiv, [State1,State2|Require]]), */
  Params = [Trans1, Trans2, Accept1, Accept2],
  (member(State1,Accept1) -> member(State2,Accept2) ; \+member(State2,Accept2)),
  find(State1, Equiv, Set1, Equiv2), plus(State2, NegState2, 0),
  (member(NegState2,Set1) -> check(Params, Equiv, Require);
   find(NegState2, Equiv2, Set2, Equiv3), union(Set1, Set2, SetU),
   (P =.. [next_state, State1, State2]),
    foldl(P, Trans1, Trans2, RequireMore, Require),
   check(Params, [SetU|Equiv3], RequireMore)).

/* Top-level goal. Parse two DFAs from standard input, and check
   for equivalence. */
run :- get(a(Transitions1, [Init1], Accept1)), get(a(Transitions2, [Init2], Accept2)),
  (check([Transitions1, Transitions2, Accept1, Accept2], [], [Init1, Init2])
   -> R=y; R=n), print(R).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VpLb@TIkb73r6DnJHmrZWYymSRnMAYaaw8wgOeBntmTLDTYakoqTKmorWK1pm2v/3pvxhePTEqygb3tYRoQm4/MeHwRGRkRWQ@HeTffvj4@bj9//sPvqx/Hw3Gqxmq33U/VzWG@r47Lh@2@Go/VcjdVy3S4r95cvKqq6pv5kF5tj9XDYb49jPebPCC9nH59mK6X6UO1zNX7RJBm/Gmir9v99rhsr6tv0s0yVW9Oy3w/LvO@SlyIws18uKfRVTWe/XwY98ftsp33P4/vd9Omuvw2TdqOu6tN9eb6enpYtvvb84vq9394dTstZ2/Oqy9fV4dp/PDuuBzSp7PTcTq82@4fTsum@uKv@y8ShTT13ab66XwDWXXgm81P5xevXiUEklwfIMhP00Iypf9@uEmXY/V4t72@q67n/TJu98fq2001pqGH6X7@OFXbheFKM0n63Xi4nQ55MiD74VBtb6r9XB1PiRDRn35NYBw3VZITPOf99HraTffTfsH3y2@vkgzHJakEbiA9jR@nQqzT/vpu3N9OH4DDTRL/LIlm33G7qd5Ox4XgSRSOicP1cobXxTCM2FT30/376SAk0vPvLl6imQQrngW6v8zzL9XpAZrsp1@X5DvjIm40Vof5sZpv0s1iVq0WNut8IMWWx7mYduR51/PhMB0f5n3ywluiwVC@qf42HWbyNPjMuN2dDpPwI6uMu8fx05FepOu48OjH7XI3n5Zql@Q8PQAu4vcO087qzbvz6vXrP1aX9dVF@eEnum7ezo/y@fv0KWn/9/1y5/LHDb0@/5/nM90G/3ka5OjiQQc@/nwsDUqoP/3geSLj/J930/Uv5EqE2J@@eZM0TMpP/33afhx3yXV@94qI/5meCaExWXwh6I/kLun/h5ng/6h4JeturxXvRM4R@9uRRhCdlwd59v6a1mvicD3f3yd7rgxxUb25SWtMl8S4u50PyQL31d1IAWJMoSAFiLF6GLcHiAezb2gp3Y@/JF5HIpWWRCVLgqikFcmK2Tp8Py93icd8nMxxkkg3p4VmpxBzGMnVjkma3Q4rz5Q6EjWiT/gQhEtiAr13n1JYm46ne4tgGd0LoPuWXhCDhO@@mj5O@9fp420SZZeW9EX154/T4ZOpJgocxRy2LBAWE@JJ5N1ufkzc3n9aDSigJlhOx4WEOd7NjxQtk2OT@xMXomQYIgKbwF9yOHUX1bc3rC5bFJKPCKPFykEYSpcDDdjPC8d18jImQ5ZMen//w88rTPDBX1Q/0NTH7TGt6uSgsI3IRLMkxh/H@0kCDQkNgyanm43DzekAEdLekpzuSEufpJmmDwmiG@w8U3V9SqEhBUpSf1OlQdcT@4GREc5p/GHajbQdyZvHKQkz7mir@JSsP@1FgWalADGaxhSqd9NCjizSi6@Pu4e78T0FUYwzLIw7VmayGiQnNcbkEWa0VaQTjcr1bGSeoUxyjsmdP8BYR7Y/FnZJM7mt@qiSx2dbEQW19xfVd1PasDhCyMoi0EuYbckkyrbg0wQjQ/8oxNoS/bd8w0WS72FKaJz2y3ZHvshbenW/PaaMIMG@JWROyScTHR5UrLrp/mH5lHVIrv30Y/bcJ/Hx4lWK/NcURM/ebd5tLq9SXOXHlP6M98cNO@TlKnz/Q8hfyS6a4jClKuNy9gWGf1n98@GfexnED5RuiG//C1pXKdQnWaqKGVdfV5fIeVIIxv9e8xynN/5qk4afyS4tVGVM2lf@WJVfvHxJO85X1V//4@VP50QQW7xQ0/WYdnZ98EnOh93pqHOr76dbva3PS4nyB5oOiVbQKnFB4PwrsiC4FySZJyTQpyZJcNon9zljsfhTuv4X2FdnP1ZfX1xUl3njTF9FHyZ7xQMp1H7Ynf0oCBdIi0jfzYcpy4c5aw0uies/WKqr1bRz2aB/nh/SbpC2kep2HncXklXb6pa8OkXb8ZDiOqenFHvBB4CUEeV6QqpyOO0pvaVEt8yMSQOkxc6SYpds@nycl3Hexontz1i9yzXN9cznXohMmhlvKqZ7TqIng7/9@tNX6bInp0nZ9XL29vzi8@fx7PIyUYqbytXpL6S//tmjb9PfsKmaJv2lbyF9C@k@RH5um/X4l@bGmsfivttUXRKwS9@6dN@n@z7R6Ok@zRnS2CEwn6FnPq4mgjVRd05eObr4mgk5T1L4ji7DE5kaJ2@VqyNRXMB3GkjkiLsLAw8gESMxa2k0iLU0pU3fXSRysRFSUbRwXc2quM7zTRR9WDTMV0Z4TW9IV0fKu56@03v6bq8JBzd4FXQgRsMgyoO/AeNxR8zlsRd4GBUSHWQxPTbyyrvWhBt0AinsXSeiexiVQPTeleR6G0Fm7hUv0huwAGaP4aGx2UqRH@kDIb0GK89xXf4uhghmFyLfBLq0ahzITxbyzYoGC4TH4BQFYuiDF2C7UnaMwkwf4Me1ghuiyg428HASAo7JZmzFOTAfVoJqZEffdvIY1T5s7Chq0xPbzhh5aAZ3pfHQlodA0uhLfYwsLOtJIVbDqRr9ynVbHemVKrTpnHqEKdOsBoAw@BMqvjFk4agQIJi@eRnhK/wLsIIKsF2tZhivc8oUA8hlgQR7FGiQ6lExbluVAxLB4ESVTUkrEh8AUOHrNAsrkBhAHujYt6ofuTnTpXexl1exp2BL4BAfokRmWD16yJEiX83PpBUJEyi6pXvSC@5cTH9pLjkazcV94k9q0H3XM50@5LGDjB0ouhC9GhEBoQLk6RHMsCzwjng5T4J4LPWnYkH@xmfGjheX07kkBAY4UknF5KVKHPjJ@MFjYxBakSxPI7K4HdkDRu3oI@Jrls@4AQMvs10fVLN@kAEKAsQFn6HNb33tROKMj8ddVMGzCll8D1wIR@@achzH3kG4sBtBHhKdFyx7gmrtvRiOlWvFxJ5eSdSKohOzUnQLiiBm/J7ghYVgY9mJXVdaBzNdWNGACtAU@yQEKTTKg53YDOYyM4I9lgkimGsEBrxqnY6HFUl6D0GydQaxPdg1tYGoTsPQZUKmRwcG/UoWfMysYi1@W2BMQ6AVC8KLaUU4e4G3rdXHgRce1IWqbAvThsXG/Khfs80K9xgsBsPIBdRNaWDRu1xTbNtG9tBsM5gGKjIvpwZiuvAPbAqdsmHfaFRs363dmH3I6bTezPaS1/hs9sY0a4Uv5haUwbIp9KaomihjGyOp6eX6ESE@uQZFOgoiFAU9f6dNhTwDG04xvZxLaQN5CUUhGktBnoxJzkTLh1SHcVumS9GEtu5Bnl1dMyNXR5bCkZ5442QHxgPtqC8JpIwd1EbuQjpwEhb4uwMFGoWbECzz0fQnDsIPr@gJI2mvgPFo@8SYTj7zAyJlnTVkRg1e@6wob9mNqGxvMXgQoNyAxVCLHNjQKXwruL4G@h0z8xw76wwoT4X@7IexlFhzmUbJYjN2cDBfwA2ZgF3TP0VEtIAHK4yQCqbzXpkV@OLOeGbwm74ckWOLsmIGsGjrNd80OQhaH@oSV848DALPCX4vGPlgaS5TAoGh1IGxADNIwuGvFXeUnKs1eoY1XZimehdLIlbJc2AjdUiGLRtD3ZPRIa@L/Uqf2FqCGnlxsRJ1V7h5dtmo@hELANrpEukaJde0JVcQdhkoAlksYI/I0WHi1lL2uDYBB2e3MjRPKwKD74yXLVjIq37q8zcUiJmg@aCYZP3BxGKeYciLlUnaUABSyGHCJ4UoaNLeSZzIFciC60fCi/ZTSpsoFR34OdAKp4LZP5tdTqXUhHJv5MhkOzIpZV@BSVJEIbypjFE2FCaIDYpW7B010iVsPggaQsgh7yWWnJbHF0VS1o5iPiqiBssBwbItvtO8qGVY1AXcYfHBtrXC3qgAXPYNKqdy6EQrh4CKPoXoaBgEnYhYiooY/QvcOCEIsbiUj@V7FoVQ8YCGHpF54Ak2QNQFWpABS5lTeM1aHJd4jcgt6hmBtlfqqGNQmNEuaMAjrwWKhCeANXAwh3OZFbI1SiLUos4quyCGAB1mCdVQFwAZ0OWApfkVyplaGXBHQZHBssJCA0Vk@@uhBCIkHswOHRYOAmqneR1Kl7pQgGHIYmfbEEUMZVMiK4xiVCjLnqVAwDw0ERlR6EpRYJNsTkPFR4Uhqm6sM5ecwfImgcdzSe/0os7OFDs1KGSBcgYZlOjCylZoKNjyYOMg80Iihhyo1kmDaMlzegEWXsO6ZgRb87DOoOWkNbuKl7kaPASIRjBm1ZtYRnfP@0avDHXv5ffsKUgqVQ1b5r43GghKUE8bJHjFN/3V1ebS0V96SgErxZ7kU2iCdkg7B@kkOkngGukqtpzMoYTouXbntovU7o0E3ZZLPN9xZEQntZbs1UtXNUhQjlLn9xw50Wl1nIKh4xokYEeu@2n3RKSsJcn03PmkhUW7AzLdjhOyVrqw2Kl9EcnFa7TlGSXuoVfqJSsO0q2N3OukTIPWWS8tT0TFhsshcuK@aHP20nekoDfIrkBLxArxjru8XPzXtlV42y@C1ecaelwuONg0zhobjYRGaXFY/QoTOev6eGtdcL8xSLrufLQ2ci9dY2l/OG1xNBZqG@slo8GAPb6xXh13w6x3m@MjakV2Z@tFtfUL8dFas9xE660DXVvO4LWZy5WxFZu8o/UWFWupCLiHyf2V8LzJgvKAd7tatjzOo7hHHWyjixoi0dlEw4W7y04b1kNjgbW1na@THNdx/6XWUrX2GhzrIE2YXD1I0a3lA/ov3vovHOK5yIyrZifXCrV2UbEquV0dtN/ptUON9B0FQY6ViFhSGGuXWerVbrUzhVq7jGh5cpc52D4UdTMKmjR67ns4yd89x8Ag@TtHw7aTbgY3PaMGTDQ90aDggBlzGthpmI62M3Ta9vScxQbJa5FHckGOugHbJjYxNEpRr/SNhlHsTJzbdRw0z1/R2ZEeByAA1dqq0pDUa/vXfLuIn8SGOGMh1baG6i6H0F6Kb9IB4a8pQpeEw5waQVNniKA275UsUNa0vBP6CK2OQykq@CFrAk@zGwQS8m9CHAZkv9QLTELegogaWGzwEn@JOahKUy1qN4ocjw@lWGCsw0ZRUsQa/gAfVCbspFaXIcLqG@QrnC7n3Jb/gkIA94bfNwIPIOIIG8vgyv6FUMTBNagK7MPOYm3@atNYS6@RZB1cJXH1eqF3Qf4koPZluVX6AkcDBOFeAwGoZA/giaVlJLSWxQIu8HgzFiR1aiiADWPHWEAvodXpeibNONC2q8hai4txcO2fA2sIcWLmNaE3INp8ktLI3VAXx4TMP2qpbrGsV8VqlTtqnV1eVqE0hmfGtEVh@HDq5qwzQR7Qr6Ioh9IcRTsLoE@iaPvvLhxP9cLhpXVlFM1WYofEclzHRY6k0dAOFknrJ0GUyminqcDKnb3q23Bq57QybXXH6Mu9jETBbukt/6@tU4qFbYe1SHz4THeQNKrRifAmaTLCKyInlJIUaZrZiyxe@8rcnRQxZUMbskp8ouu0nwZnxx7W2GYbbDu1Ah35gjNBgzDlRKuVDcCLq7DXBdmuOhXD8fbecJ7oFQ0RsZZvijHxQY4of4KmiYsDAssj5OcC3G5QOIqcz0nLQ5JJtQltu8oQKZs4lmphK0A/iIAgx9SFCp8acC4Z2GB8k3FFutCW5wiSj9aWuXR29q4fJIn0llPWeuEUTi@F1RQ939gyUVeW01Svl9ZOvbj2H0ww80BRNB9bFN87veQ0s7E0c@XfPv/MobVkMsh7BkBFN@uy/gC8tORKF3Zt@qo1YSY4WKYoa6U0pCuNy@tiMIeUm@Y5zzqXEm1maGe5vi5mraWxpJRLklDwsJwwXxrt7mZAmWb73Ael6Gs0gJXxPbKmkoR2WtCgQpDDaoqLKEQbq3Rk47JDXT07buynIsjmkDNpwYFUAzUDKtzWzmoHPfDQA@5afzQRdBr38xsrqPTnMlhAYcg6rPYuUNSeB6cWnKr3cjcI6fyGJY3izkF7GUiPw1pQL6NR90YRHb9UqXlClPYYtm3SF5V2r3O5bdVYYVujxRDlLEXR5fKy5hIYpXHQwyCrDO0EE8Cg1pe/7tljVPntImcyUrTKbxSsZNaTBSlo@vId5yKNHR7j6zMHEFO04l1Ky5AsiBakgvpAvkNCQ@PMNl1T@E82Yu5QBuk2S0HdlpdcPnE5C6RRfSM/74eMmzNJFDG3ggB3XNzahUvf9YWL284KXmsScrHcrbwC7Hib0Mvas7mU5Ho3X@pnl0EPcLgKrbWNLr2PLi9fQ/elP8s31zI9WXOd@g/WTTayW8FYOGTHeEKg3CAO5rkStFqn7beg01pdZy434LDx1dqrpy4DaD5pwUU9lUIHB70Ip2eX/MsgOcyVnje5BjyjaKY0zKyRJjm6bl4KeqTsvfDSPnvni15cw3@NtOJaJiI/FIhF880OdEMWzQ@5G8cFY6xzP44bQ/ZDIz2GDNKmDDoePQ7pxvh1W06m26nUwHp2Blujp96@/OUBpyOBaaDvEe2XRXWfi0j1qE6O71ptj3Mp3OipH3dcJX/iPq3sZkLEyjZudxlenR2Y6TFjlNFcHtjPANFDFaH1IL7tMo5cVeWLvGIuYqbesIqZbv9C5623x15cRIFhT@i0ENVPg54@RDnJkEZRZw00hqfjJWGngny4HQsbYERQBwuaHcDmdvTNLTAvjS9IowkUesdBp8IX5Adf8vNAZx218C96a4294xlKkUFT5LJF7YgnlhdnIklfbdVIi4P@5EsDdywCmLdfBXBnj7tprbXe@lIaIdoWmpaS4FzAp8tvpwK/nQr8fzoVCL8dDfx2NPB/ORq4On/1@fXy@XDa/y8)

Comment: Very nice to see a Prolog solution.

Comment: Though it's yet another case of "seems like Prolog's built-in backtracking support might be useful" then "okay, didn't actually rely much on backtracking after all".